# How to use `polygon()` in log scale?

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I basically want to shade an area behind a graph.

It's easy enough to do in linear scale.

```
x <- 1:20
y <- x^2
plot(x, y, type="l")
polygon(c(10,10,15,15),
        c(-100,600,600,-100),
        col=rgb(0,1,0,0.3),border=FALSE)
```

Produces this:

[image]

But once you put *y* on a log scale,

```
plot(x, y, type="l", log="y")
polygon(c(10,10,15,15),
        c(-100,600,600,-100),
        col=rgb(0,1,0,0.3),border=FALSE)
```

Nothing shows up.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use plot(x, log(y), type = "l') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful when playing with `log = "y"`. If your `y` value is negative, you get `NaN`. This is exactly what happened here. Try

```
plot(x, y, type="l", log="y")
polygon(c(10,10,15,15),
        c(1e-7,600,600,1e-7),  ## log(1e-7) is small enough
        col=rgb(0,1,0,0.3),border=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zheyuan!